# PROTEUS: How to add a binary firmware, from an unsupported compiler?

Tags: hardware, simulation, firmware, pic32, isis

In ISIS design tool there are many options of compilers, as well as microcontroller families and their variants with which we can perform compilation and simulation in the Proteus IDE.

However, although it is possible to install other compilers that are not configured by default, there is no option for many other compilers, such as for example the PIC32 from Microchip.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused since you mentioned binary image in the question title and talks about compilation in the body.

Proteus does support loading pre compiled images in hex of elf format.

Comment: Ok thanks, in fact I did not stated the question as it should be. I was referring to install another compiler, that not in the default list.